# CSS: how to bring child image in front of parent background image?

Tags: html, css

I have a background image set on the `.section` class in CSS.  On that, I have an opacity as well.  My child `img` is a transparent png however it's showing behind the background image on the div and it's also inheriting the opacity i have on the background image.  How can I bring this to the top?  I tried using z-indexes but it was not solving it.

```css
.section {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-image: url(/image/bg.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
.section:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #000000, #000000);
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <img class="logo" src={ "imgafi2x.png"}/>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to be really particular when you are using `z-index`es. Are you using React? You haven't even completely added your code.

Comment: I am, yes.  I added the relevant parts.  I didn't think adding the entire component would be necessary

Comment: No no... You added it right, but just the closing `}` is missed. So wait, you have got a `::before` pseudo element to come on top, is it?

Comment: ah yea, i left off the closing tag when copying it over but the `}` is there in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using the below code:

> **Note:** I didn't add snippet because it was React & SCSS. Stack Snippets don't support both React & SCSS. That's the reason I have linked to JSBin.

```
.section {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-image: url(//placehold.it/500?text=BG);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:relative;
  &:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#000000,#000000);
    opacity: .6; 
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;                 /* Change Here */
    z-index: 2;                         /* Change Here */
  }
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/lepahirifa**

Comment: @RaymondK Check out the updated answer... See the preview and stuff, is that what you wanted?

Comment: ah yes, there we go.  Why does the `position: relative` in the logo class make that work now?  How does that effect z-index

Comment: `.logo { position: relative; }` would have been enough. There is no need to add any `z-index`s @PraveenKumarPurushothaman

Comment: @Turnip yep, looks that way.  How does `positive: relative` effect stack order though.  I always thought ( and used) positioning attribute for x/y positioning

Comment: It creates a new stacking context, and so moves the element above the previous elements. This is why your `:before` pseudo element was overlaying the image; It was positioned with `absolute` (new stacking context).

Comment: @RaymondK Sorry was travelling. Glad that you have got it solved. `:D`